# Python - Using a list split values into specific grade values

Tags: python, list

I have a list of scores:

```
scores = [50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 56, 56, 61, 64, 67, 68, 71, 79, 81, 86, 86, 87, 94, 96, 98, 99]
```

i want to sort them into grades:

A: 90% +
B: 80% - 89%
C: 70% - 79%
D: 60% - 69%
E: 50% - 59%

not entirely sure how I go about doing it!

I've tried something like this:

```
def grade (score):
if score >= 90:
    return "A"
if score >= 80:
    return "B"
if score >= 70:
    return "C"
if score >= 60:
    return "D"
if score >= 50:
    return "E"
return "F"
```

i want it to output into the list as en example:

```
[50 - E, 51 - E, 53 - E, 55 - E]
```

and so on for the higher score

Comment: Please can you include the expected output plus please share your effort too.

Comment: Also, any code you've tried so far?

Comment: Sorry about that guys! Here you go hope that helps!

Comment: Your expected output in not well formed.  Do you expect something like this `[(50, 'E'), (51, 'E'), ....]`. OR in a dictionary format like this `{'A':[94, 96, 98, 99], 'B':[81, 86, 86, 87], .....}`

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to this, ill keep that in mind for next time at least i got an answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     In [21]:

    scores = [50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 56, 56, 61, 64, 67, 68, 71, 79, 81, 86, 86, 87, 94, 96, 98, 99]

    score_categories = {'[' + str(k) + '% - ' + str(k+10) + '%)': [v for v in scores if k <= v < k+10] for k in range(50, 100, 10)}

    for k,v in score_categories.items():
        print k + ' : ' + str(v)

[80% - 90%) : [81, 86, 86, 87]
    [90% - 100%) : [94, 96, 98, 99]
    [70% - 80%) : [71, 79]
    [60% - 70%) : [61, 64, 67, 68]
    [50% - 60%) : [50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 56, 56]
```

**EDIT:**

```
 def grade(score):
        if score >= 90:
            return "A"
        if score >= 80:
            return "B"
        if score >= 70:
            return "C"
        if score >= 60:
            return "D"
        if score >= 50:
            return "E"
        return "F"   

    score_categories2 = [str(v) + ' - ' + grade(v) for v in scores]
    print score_categories2

    ['50 - E', '51 - E', '53 - E', '55 - E', '56 - E', '56 - E', '56 - E', '61 - D', '64 - D', '67 - D', '68 - D', '71 - C', '79 - C', '81 - B', '86 - B', '86 - B', '87 - B', '94 - A', '96 - A', '98 - A', '99 - A']
```

Comment: You don't actually want range(50,100,10) since that won't sort low values.

Comment: @user3467349 why do i not want range(50, 100, 10)?  The first part of the answer was posted before OP clarified his desired output.

Comment: Because your scores less then 50 will not show up anywhere.

Comment: I agree.  I followed OP grade scale.  He did not have values less then 50 (i.e. E: 50% - 59%)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dictionary version:

```
grades = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': [], 'D':[], 'F': []}
grade_baselines = [('A',90), ('B', 80), ('C', 70), ('D', 60), ('F', 0)]
def sort_grades(score):
    for score in scores:
        for letter, baseline in grade_baselines:
            if baseline < score < baseline+10: 
                grades[letter].append(score)
```

output:

```
Out[41]: 
{'C': [71, 79],
 'A': [94, 96, 98, 99],
 'D': [61, 64, 67, 68],
 'B': [81, 86, 86, 87],
 'F': []}
```

---

*edit:* As Haken pointed out in the comment for a slight performance gain you can use a break on the comparison as long as `grade_baselines` is sorted correctly.

```
if baseline < score: 
   grades[letter].append(score) 
   break
```

Comment: Drop `baseline+10` and use a `break` instead.

Comment: @HakenLid I updated below - you'd probably need *a lot* of grades before it makes a credible difference, and then you would do better to use numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, your input list always contains values between 50 and 99, then you can use your code; I'd just suggest to add a small modification.

```
gradeA = []
gradeB = []
# etc.

for score in scores:
    if score >= 90:
        gradeA.add(score)
    else if score >= 80:
        gradeB.add(score)
    # etc.
```

That code first creates lists for every grade. Then it iterates over every item in the input list and uses the else/if statements to determine what grade you got. Based on that the score is added to the equivialent list. Obviously you can put that into a function.

Now, if you have input values with a different range, you obviously need to find out what the highest value is.

```
highest = 0
for score in scores:
    if score > highest:
        highest = score
```

Then you can use the calculate the values for 90%, 80%, etc.